# How to set legend to print Y values vertically

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am using a legend to show the values of Y because some values can be as long as 1000000 and when they're plotted on the graph they collide. How can I plot the values vertically instead of horizontally? Excuse my photoshop.

```
ax.bar(x,y,align='center', width=0.2, color = 'm', label = y)
for key, frequency1_value in frequency1.most_common(response1):
    ax.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still need help, anyone?...

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Post x,y and frequency1.most_common(response1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to create a string containing the numbers. Here is a minimal working example (you will have to change the x labels to the IP addresses).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numbers = [3539, 1408, 1320, 1284, 1243, 1164, 1001, 582, 582, 562]
x = range(len(numbers))
text = ''
for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    text += '{}\n'.format(numbers[i])
text += '{}'.format(numbers[-1])
plt.bar(x, numbers, label=text, color='m')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

This will produce an output similar to the one you wish. [image: Plot]